# Do maps in groovy maintain order?

Tags: data-structures, groovy

Do maps in groovy maintain order in which the data has been provided? I.e. when iterating over keys, will the order be preserved at all times?

`farms = [Idaho: ["Duck", "Dog"], Ohio: ["Chicken", "Duck"], "New Mexico": ["Dog", "Cow"]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. When you use the map literal syntax in groovy it creates an instance of a `LinkedHashMap`, which will maintain order. This can be seen in [this ideone](http://ideone.com/p5g5PA).

**Just a Note**

In my experience (not always, mind you) if you need to maintain the order of a `Map` then you might not be using it in the correct way. There aren't many real use cases that call for this type of map.

Comment: That was precisely my thought, got used to the idea that maps do not possess such quality. I saw a few groovy tutorials that seemed to assume such a behavior which surprised me. Though I share your view on maps usage, it seems significant that groovy implements maps in that way. Is it "the groovy way" to exploit that feature?

Comment: There is a general philosophy within the groovy syntax, that it 'just works'. You want to get a value from a map? `map.get('myValue')`, `map['myValue']` and `map.myValue` are all valid. Want to get a substring? `myStr[5..10]` works. The language is dripping with sugar, which makes it heavy, but also a fantastic language to develop with. This is just another way that the groovy devs have made your life easier. You incur minimal performance hits with a `LinkedHashMap` and it's just one more thing that the map literal can do.